# JQuery Autocomplete DIV Style Change?

Tags: html, jquery, css

I have a div that contains the Jquery autocomplete classes for a input that looks something like this:

```css
[class*="ui-autocomplete-multiselect"][class*="form-control"] {
  border-radius: 5px;
  color: black;
  /* padding: 50x; this works */
}
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
  <div class="input-group input-group-sm flex-nowrap">
    <label for="test">Test Label</label>
    <div class="ui-autocomplete-multiselect ui-state-default ui-widget form-control">
      <input id="test" class="form control col-sm-12 ui-autocomplete-input">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I'm trying modify the CSS border and color of the input div that contains the autocomplete class but nothing is changing. If I was to add padding, I see the padding changes but why aren't any of the color or border styles changing?

Comment: If you are trying to edit the input's color, I would add **input** after the form-control to change the input's color. The padding works because I'm assuming the autocomplete element has the border applied to it and the input has its border removed in CSS. So you are seeing padding AROUND the actual input.

Comment: the input is inside the DIV which, itself, has different styling. I found that the only way to override the Jquery autocomplete styles is to add `!important` to all properties. Not sure if there is a better way to do it..,